# How to constantly track a QWidget's global position

Tags: qt, widget

### In short

I realise I can use `mapToGlobal(...)` to get the widgets position relative to the screen, I want to be track when this changes as it changes.

### In long

There is a `QMoveEvent` when a `QWidget` moves compared to its parent, but there is no `QEvent` for when a widget moves relative to the screen.

There are a couple of ways it can move relative to the screen without an event firing; if any widget sharing a common parent is moved or resized or if the window framing changes.

### What I've tried

Currently I'm filtering all move and resize events of the specific widgets ancestors, however siblings or aunts/uncles could also easily cause a change in global position, I don't want to track every single widget in my project for the sake of one...

I feel like there has to be a better way but I've verified that there are no events to capture through testing and I can't see anything in the documentation nor can I find any other people asking the same question...

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that you need to track the siblings. You do need to track the position of all of the ancestors. It's not hard to do.

Comment: I'm using `QMdiSubWindow` which is all `QWidgets` as far as I'm aware, changing the title-bar height moved the widget but none of the parents updated... perhaps its a style issue then?

Comment: @Troyseph I don't understand what you mean by "none of the parents updated". Of course the parent widgets won't change, but the `QMdiSubWindow`'s `geometry()` has changed but not its `pos()`. Please post a complete example of code you have problems with and/or elaborate what exact scenario do you have in mind. There's no way to track a widget's frame size changes, but the contents (the `geometry()`) stays fixed with relation to the parent and/or the screen, as appropriate.

Comment: That's exactly my problem, `the position of the parent widgets didn't change, however the absolute position of the child did` basically I have no way of detecting the change in absolute screen position. I'm not trying to work around the example I gave, I'm trying to work out exactly what I need to track to achieve absolute screen position tracking.

Comment: @Troyseph I still don't know what your problem is. If `geometry` of any widget up the parent chain did change relative to screen, then your widget has moved. If it didn't, it did not. If you claim otherwise, you must post a counter-example as that would be a Qt bug.

Comment: I'm on it, the code is part of a very large project so it may take a while to create a counter-example. Hopefully a bug in our code becomes apparent to me while doing this!